# nodejs - shasum mismatch

Tags: node.js, sha

There must be something simple I am missing. I am not sure, why the SHA sums wouldn't match. The sums are generated with `nodejs` and `shasum` on Linux command line.

```
user@host:~$ nodejs
> var c = require('crypto')
undefined
> c.createHash('sha1').update('Hello world!','ascii').digest('hex')
'd3486ae9136e7856bc42212385ea797094475802'

user@host:~$ shasum -
Hello world!
47a013e660d408619d894b20806b1d5086aab03b  -
```

I did try with different options such as `ascii` and `utf-8` with `nodejs` and `shasum`; but, mismatch exists. Of course, for simple English text, `ascii` and `utf-8` shouldn't matter.

Although, since the applications generating and using the hashes will be `nodejs` applications; and, so, it probably wouldn't matter. But, I cannot get around the fact that the sums would be different.

Can you please guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `shasum` is getting an extra new line character (`\n`).

```
$ echo Hello world! | shasum
47a013e660d408619d894b20806b1d5086aab03b  -
-------------------------------------------
$ node
> var c = require('crypto')
undefined
> c.createHash('sha1').update('Hello world!').digest('hex')
'd3486ae9136e7856bc42212385ea797094475802'
> c.createHash('sha1').update('Hello world!\n').digest('hex')
'47a013e660d408619d894b20806b1d5086aab03b'
```

Comment: echo -n "Hello world!"|sha1sum